# ML.NET Price Prediciton model with collection of user-defined values

Tags: c#, ml.net

Trying to add ML.NET to software for estimating property values, but the catch is that customers using the software are allowed to create user-defined custom fields for `Property` objects. Picture the following data:

```
public class Property
{
    public int PropertyId { get; set; }
    public float Size { get; set; }
    public string ZipCode { get; set; }
    // etc.

    public float SalePrice { get; set; }

    public ICollection<PropertyCustomField> CustomFields { get; set; }
}

public class PropertyCustomField
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

I would want to build and train a Model to predict the `SalePrice` of the property, however it is unknown how many `PropertyCustomField` entries a property will have or what they will be, but they will generally be shared among other `Property` records in the system. They will absolutely contain data relevant to the value of the property so they cannot be simply disregarded. I've gone though many ML.NET guides for price prediction but I have not found one for this circumstance. Is there anyway to translate this arbitary data to something that can be categorized for training and use by a Model?